# How to check that a div exists jquery and if it does do nothing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check to see if an div called .errormsg exists and if it does then I don't want anything to happen but if it doesn't exist i want my form to redirect to a new URL after it. This is what I've done but I'm not sure it's correct at all, I'm only learning so any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById('.errormsg')` ??? At least, read the DOC

Comment: like I said I'm only learning :)

Comment: Learn by searching first. Study the results. Ask questions when you are really unsure and did everything to solve your problem. Also, code review is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Check with a length property of a jQuery object

```
if($('div.errormsg').length==0)
{
 //Not exists, so redirect
 //window.location.href='newurl';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
if (document.getElementById('.errormsg')) {
```

to this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('errormsg').length) {
```

[document.getElementsByClassName docs @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.length` property to check the existance of element/elements:

```
if(!$('.errormsg ').length){//does ot exist
  //redirect
}
```

Comment: $('.errormsg ').length will not return any boolean

Comment: You should at least test the code before commenting something like that.`$(!0)` returns true....you can check in console.

Comment: yeah.. its true .. my bad